# Electrolysis Current Question

Tags: power-supply, electrolysis

I have seen images online that show the current of electrons going from Negative to Positive in electrolysis with water but with my knowledge, the electron flow should flow from Positive to Negative. I am having issues finding out why this is which is why I have come to the Electrical Engineering side of this website. For electrolysis, is the flow POS ---> NEG or NEG ---> POS? Thanks and sorry for dumb question

Answer (score 2):

Note that during electrolysis, there are no electrons flowing in the water.

During electric currents inside electrolytes, the charge-carriers are charged atoms (ions.)  In acids, the main charge-carrier is the proton (also called the +H ion.)

For example, in salt water, an electric current is made up of positive +Na ions flowing one way, and negative -Cl ions flowing the other.  Imagine them as two clouds flowing through each other without interacting.

Now ask yourself this:  inside a single conductor, if two groups of charges are flowing in opposite directions, *which is the "real" direction of the current?*  If there are opposite charges moving oppositely, how can there be a single direction, or a single current?

Simple answer: the purpose of "Conventional Current" is to conceal all the complicated stuff inside conductors.  Stuff like positive and negative ions flowing in salt water (or in acids, or alkaline solutions.)

Electron-flows are made of Conventional Current.   Ammeters measure Conventional Current.

"Conventional Current" happens whenever we add the flows of positive particles to the reversed flows of negative particles.   For salt water, just subtract the negative -Cl amperes from the positive +Na amperes, and that gives us a single number in amps.   (Subtracting a negative number will increase the total Conventional Current, of course.)

Note that human bodies are made of salt water.  Whenever you get a shock, no electrons flowed through your body at all.   The amperes were made of flowing +Na, +K, -Cl, +H, and -OH charged ion particles.   If we try to inject electrons into salt water (or into human skin,) the electrons won't go in.  Instead  we just get chemistry at the surface, where the positive ions rush to meet with the incoming electrons from the metal wire.  The two cancel out, forming neutral metals (sodium and potassium,) while the +H ions cancel with electrons to produce hydrogen gas.   At the surface, electrons and positive atoms are flowing together and neutralizing.

Finally:  inside metals, the movable charge-carriers are the negative electrons.  For this reason, it SEEMS like conventional current must be backwards.  But actually it's only a problem for metal conductors.  Out in nature, metallic conductivity is rare, and most electric currents are flows of positives and negatives, both at the same time in opposite directions.  Whenever pos and neg are flowing in opposite directions, there is no "One True Direction," and no "Backwards."

Weird trivia:  suppose we rotate a metal wire circuit slowly backwards against the electric current, so the electrons stop in place.  The current doesn't stop.  Instead, the electric current is now composed of positive copper ions moving forward!   This demonstrates that electric current inside wires was never a negative flow at all.   Instead it was a *relative flow* between the metal's electron-sea and the metal's positive-charged atom grid.  If we say that "electrons flow in wires," that's only true for non-moving wires.   If the metal is moving, then both the positives and the negatives are flowing.  The difference between their flows is called "amperes of conventional current."

Answer (score 0):

Electrons always flow *towards* positive.

Conventional current flows the other way - from positive to negative. This convention was established before the discovery of the electron by J.J. Thompson.

> For electrolysis, is the flow POS ---> NEG or NEG ---> POS?

For electrolysis the charge carriers could be electrons (-) or positive ions (+). They will always migrate to the opposite polarity node. (The common word for anode / cathode escapes me just now.)

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of current. I am self teaching myself this stuff so thank you for helping me understand this better.

Comment: I've added a little more regarding electrolysis.

Comment: @Transistor - you may be thinking of "electrode".

Answer (score 0):

ELECTRONS flow from negative to positive,

CURRENT flows form positive to negative.

If you remember electrons have a negative charge you may be able to understand it better.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of current. I am self teaching myself this stuff so thank you for helping me understand this better.